# How to debug java in maven plug with angular 2, tomee in docker

Tags: java, maven, docker, intellij-idea

I have a project with 2 maven plugin.

1. Plugin is in java.
2. Another Plugin is angular2.
3. Over these 2 maven plugins is docker.

In docker container, tomee and mysql runs.  I want to debug java with the front-end which means by hitting `http://localhost:8080/mywebapp` , the system should stop at the break point I set in backend (java file). I am using IntelliJ.

Does somebody know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running you application in docker container remote debugging is the only way. you could,

1. Attach remote debugging information by following [these](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) steps. This will means that you have to expose additional port apart from tomcat 8080 port.
2. Expose port in DockerFile and map it on the host. This could be done using -p flag or doing [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/).
3. In intellij-idea, do [remote debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/run-debug-configuration-remote.html). This is when you hit `http://localhost:8080/mywebapp`.

Answer (score 0):

with Gauraj's suggestions I have modified the 3 files:
1. docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '2.0'

    services: 
      db:
        build: 04.MySQL/

      tomee:
        build: .
        depends_on:
          - db
        command: >
          /bin/bash -c "
            while ! nc -z db 3306;
            do
              echo sleeping;
              sleep 5;
            done;
            echo Connected!;
            catalina.sh run;
          "
        links: 
          - db:db
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
          - "8000:8000"

      ssl:
         build: 05.ProxySSL/
         links:
          - tomee
         ports:
          - "443:443"
          - "80:80"
```

2. Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8-jdk

MAINTAINER "Software Engineering, RWTH Aachen University"

ENV PATH /usr/local/tomee/bin:$PATH

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomee

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomee

# curl -fsSL 'https://www.apache.org/dist/tomee/KEYS' | awk -F ' = ' '$1 ~ /^ +Key fingerprint$/ { gsub(" ", "", $2); print $2 }' | sort -u
ENV GPG_KEYS \
    BDD0BBEB753192957EFC5F896A62FC8EF17D8FEF \
    223D3A74B068ECA354DC385CE126833F9CF64915 \
    7A2744A8A9AAF063C23EB7868EBE7DBE8D050EEF \
    82D8419BA697F0E7FB85916EE91287822FDB81B1 \
    9056B710F1E332780DE7AF34CBAEBE39A46C4CA1 \
    A57DAF81C1B69921F4BA8723A8DE0A4DB863A7C1 \
    B7574789F5018690043E6DD9C212662E12F3E1DD \
    B8B301E6105DF628076BD92C5483E55897ABD9B9 \
    DBCCD103B8B24F86FFAAB025C8BB472CD297D428 \
    F067B8140F5DD80E1D3B5D92318242FE9A0B1183 \
    FAA603D58B1BA4EDF65896D0ED340E0E6D545F97
RUN set -xe \
    && for key in $GPG_KEYS; do \
        gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
    done

RUN set -x \
    && curl -fSL https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/release/tomee/tomee-1.7.4/apache-tomee-1.7.4-plus.tar.gz.asc -o tomee.tar.gz.asc \
    && curl -fSL http://apache.rediris.es/tomee/tomee-1.7.4/apache-tomee-1.7.4-plus.tar.gz -o tomee.tar.gz \
    && gpg --batch --verify tomee.tar.gz.asc tomee.tar.gz \
    && tar -zxf tomee.tar.gz \
    && mv apache-tomee-plus-1.7.4/* /usr/local/tomee \
    && rm -Rf apache-tomee-plus-1.7.4 \
    && rm bin/*.bat \
    && rm tomee.tar.gz*

RUN apt update && apt install -y netcat-openbsd

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomee/webapps

COPY 03.dockerconfig/tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomee/conf/

COPY 01.Backend/lib/ /usr/local/tomee/lib/

COPY 01.Backend/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar /usr/local/tomee/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

COPY 01.Backend/target/macoco-be.war /usr/local/tomee/webapps/macoco-be.war
COPY 02.Frontend/MaCoCoLive/target/MaCoCoLive.war /usr/local/tomee/webapps/MaCoCoLive.war
COPY 01.Backend/target/apache-tomee/bin/catalina.sh /usr/local/tomee/bin/catalina.sh

EXPOSE 8080 4200 8000

CMD ["catalina.sh", "jpda run"]
```

3. catalina.sh file:

   JPDA_SUSPEND="y"
   JDPA_OPTS         -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,
                      address=8000,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND

my remote debug configuration:
[image]

Then in I run "docker-compose build" and "docker-compose up". But when I debug it, IntelliJ shows error:
"Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8000):java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection permaturally closed."

Answer (score 0):

just now I have figured out how to make it in Netbeans!

I think remote debug TomEE inside Docker in IntelliJ is impossible because the IntelliJ try to access catalina.sh inside Docker image which is not permitted by docker. But in Netbeans the server is integrated with IDE so it doesn't need to access catalina.sh.

What I do is a little tricky: first run "mvn clean install docker:stop docker:start -DskipTests tomee:run" then I have the Tomee server inside docker started. Then add this TomEE server to Netbeans (each time after rerun the mvn command, I need to add this server again).

Then just make break point and debug the maven project.

After that port8080 is occupied by Netbeans so that I cannot access localhost:8080. But I can run "npm start" to start front end in Port4200 then by every action in front end it will stop at the break point in backend.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand, you already found a solution for your remote debugging problem. If you are still interested in remote debugging from IntelliJ, feel free to use my [GitHub](https://github.com/groundhog2k/spring-docker-app) demo. Just follow the instructions on my [blog](http://blog.goeri.de/index.php/2016/01/22/how-to-install-and-remote-debug-a-java-application-on-docker-with-idea-intellij/) and it should work out-of-the-box.