# Debug JEE application in a Docker container

Tags: java, docker, debugging, docker-compose

I want to debug my containerized application running on Wildfly. But it doesn't work. :(

Dockerfile for my application:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
ADD standalone-custom.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/ 
EXPOSE 9990 
EXPOSE 8787
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-c", "standalone-custom.xml", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "--debug", "8787"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
...

services:
...

  myappservice:
    image: myappimage
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8787:8787"
      - "9990:9990"
    ...
```

When I try to attach a debugger with:

```
jdb -attach localhost:8787
```

I receive the following:

> java.io.IOException: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed
>     at
>   jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.handshake(SocketTransportService.java:142)
>     at
>   jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketTransportService.attach(SocketTransportService.java:255)
>     at
>   jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.GenericAttachingConnector.attach(GenericAttachingConnector.java:119)
>     at
>   jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.jdi.SocketAttachingConnector.attach(SocketAttachingConnector.java:83)
>     at
>   jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.attachTarget(VMConnection.java:519)
>     at
>   jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.VMConnection.open(VMConnection.java:328)
>     at jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Env.init(Env.java:63)    at
>   jdk.jdi/com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.TTY.main(TTY.java:1082)
>
> Fatal error: Unable to attach to target VM.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42707998/6162023

Comment: Did you find any solution? We are experiencing the same issues with the official  wildfly image 16.0.0.